# "Value cannout be null. Parameter: source" When upload UWP app to Microsoft Store

Tags: c#, visual-studio, deployment, uwp, windows-store-apps

When attempting to upload my package to the Microsoft Store, I get the error "Value cannot be null. Parameter name: source. Try again or upload a new package."

I have no idea what this means. Can anyone help?

The app in question was published via Visual Studio 2019 19.10.0, following the directions on the Microsoft Docs website. The app passed the Windows App Certification tests. I am currently using the latest version of Windows 10 (build 19043.98). I am uploading the .msixupload file generated by Visual Studio.

It sounds like there is some property that I haven't defined, but I have no idea what it is or where it should be.

Comment: There is something I want to confirm. Have you associated your app with Partner Center first in VS? Have you tried to upload a package that generated from a blank UWP app? Does it work?

Comment: Yes, I have associated the app with the project in the windows store. The error does not occur with a blank UWP project.

Comment: So it looks like the issue is related to your old package, not the partner center.  There used to be a similar case but it happens to Windows Application Package Project. And on that case, the issue is caused by a reference called "microsoft.windows.sdk.buildtools". If you are using WAPP as well, you could try to change it's version.

Comment: This worked perfectly, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to fix the error and want to post the solution for anyone else having this issue.

If you are using a Windows Application Packaging Project to package your app, delete the "microsoft.windows.sdk.buildtools" package by right-clicking on the packaging project in the solution explorer and select NuGet packages. From there, head to installed packages and delete "microsoft.windows.sdk.buildtools".

Comment: Glad to hear that it helps. You could mark your own reply as answer.